# Detecting credit card edges using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm hoping this is very simple; I suspect that's the case.

I have an app that takes an image from the user in which they're holding a credit card up, stripe side out. Something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2J9Q.jpg

This is already being fed through a python script to assist in pupil detection, and I'd like to add the ability to detect the edges of the credit card, width-wise. I've done some research into openCV but it seems like a VERY in-depth topic, and I believe this is a simple case.

Can anyone give me any direction on how to accomplish this? Or just how difficult it might be to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the canny edge detector, followed by HoughLines or HoughLinesP for detecting straight edges.

- Canny: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html
- HoughLines: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

But I suspect you'll have to play with the code a little bit and apply some heuristics, since I am not familiar with a module that will magically solve the problem.
In any case I would start with very basic operations (like Canny and Hough) and wouldn't try to train a detector for that.